# Drupal 7: Feed Import module setting custom elysia cron jobs 'Download of failed with code -1002.'

Tags: drupal, import, drupal-7, cron, feed

For more than a week I've been struggling with trying to create custom Elysia cron jobs for different feeds defined in Feed Import module.

I want to import data from feed AAA daily and data from feed BBB once a week. So two (or more if needed) separate tasks, that need be executed on different schedules. I have researched and combination of Elysia cron and Feed Import module seems to be the answer.

I have created two different feeds in Feed Import module. When I execute them manually from Feed Import everything works fine. When I run feed_import_base_cron task from Cron, it also works, but executes both feeds at the same time.

Problem starts when I want to define specific execution times for each feed. I have found a suggestion here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30819/give-an-individual-cron-task-for-each-feeds-import But can't make it work and don't know what I'm doing wrong, as php and drupal module development are not my strengths.

I have included code from above url in Feed Import module (feed_import_base.module). I'm not 100% sure if that's the correct place, but it kinda seems to work, as the feeds I define in code, appear in Cron tasks in administrative UI. But when I try to execute them, it results with an error, which can be seen in recent log messages:

```
    Exception: exception 'Exception' with message 'Download of failed with code -1002.' in

    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsHTTPFetcher.inc:33 Stack trace: #0     
    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsSyndicationParser.inc(20): FeedsHTTPFetcherResult->getRaw() #1 
    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsSource.inc(354): FeedsSyndicationParser->parse(Object(FeedsSource), Object(FeedsHTTPFetcherResult)) #2
    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/feed_import/feed_import_base/feed_import_base.module(622): FeedsSource->import() #3
    [internal function]: feed_import_base_fetch_test_api_feed_raw_cron(Array) #4 
    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/elysia_cron/elysia_cron.module(1090): call_user_func_array('feed_import_bas...', Array) #5
    pathToMySite../drupal/sites/all/modules/elysia_cron/elysia_cron.admin.inc(730): elysia_cron_execute('fetch_test_api_...') #6
    [internal function]: elysia_cron_execute_page('fetch_test_api_...') #7
    pathToMySite../drupal/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array('elysia_cron_exe...', Array) #8
    pathToMySite../drupal/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #9 {main}
```

The actual code I use is:

```
function feed_import_base_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
  $items['fetch_test_api_feed_raw_cron'] = array(
    'description' => 'Fetch test API feed RAW',
    'rule' => '*/10 * * * *', // Every 10 minutes
    'callback' => 'feed_import_base_fetch_test_api_feed_raw_cron' ,
    'arguments' => array(array('test_api_feed_raw'))
  );
  return $items;
}

function feed_import_base_fetch_test_api_feed_raw_cron($feednames){
  if (function_exists('feeds_source')){
    foreach($feednames as $feedname){
      $source = feeds_source($feedname);
      $source->import();
    }
  }
}
```

I really don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong and starting to run out of options what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you should start debugging from the report status page. So first navigate to '/admin/reports/status' page to check if cron runs and time of cron run. Then you should check in Drupal watchdog logs for any error during cron run related to feed.
Hope this will help you to debug your issue.

Comment: Thank you, but this is already what i'm doing and I can see I get error message "Exception: exception 'Exception' with message 'Download of failed with code -1002.'" as mentioned above. I just don't know what to do with all these messages, as I'm not so strong with php and not sure what needs to be changed there. Maybe there is something wrong with the callback function that I have added?

Comment: Hi, i will look into this issue more as i get the time but till then you can also try using this way. https://www.drupal.org/node/1534960#comment-5886094

Comment: Thank you Anurag! I have seen also that option (been googling for possible solution over a week now :) ). I didn't manage to make this work neither and kinda feel that I'm closer to the solution with the first option. It's kinda those situations when solution seems to be close, and something really obvious and simple is missing (e.g. correct call to the feed itself from callback function)

Comment: Or I might be completely wrong and have totally mixed up what goes where. I suspect that callback function in my code could be intended to work from Feeds module not from Feed Import module. Originally I'm a themer, and now I have dug too deep into module customization, would really appreciate if someone could point where I have taken wrong turn

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with a help from a colleague. Will post it here if someone would have need for it some day.

I'm missing a callback function here that triggers the actual feed import. I think the above mentioned function was developed for Feeds module not Feed Import. And thus also was not working here..

the actual function that triggers feed import is from feed_import_base.module

```
_feed_import_base_process_feed($feed);
```